# OpenCv program is not able to run ; pkg-config is hashed

Tags: opencv, installation, pkg-config

I am working with opencv libraries. When I run my project, I get following error:

OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, file /home/krathi/softwaresetup/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 483
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/krathi/softwaresetup/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:483: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvNamedWindow

When I go to terminal and type "type pkg-config" I get this:

pkg-config is hashed (/usr/bin/pkg-config)

I dont know what this means , but I guess that the access to pkg-config is only to the admin user of my machine. Am I right?

What should I do to fix this error ? Specifically what should I do so that my program can use pkg-config.

Note :I have installed libgtk

Answer (score 1):

You probably have compiled OpenCV by yourself looking at the folders given in the error message. You need to recompile OpenCV by setting WITH_GTK=ON using cmake.